# How to insert a column with multiple commas from csv to a table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, import

I am trying to import a csv into a redshift table. The import fails whenever there's extra comma value in csv

My sample csv format

```
ID, Name, Address, Contact
1, Kieron, LA, USA, 67768800
2, Diana, Baker Street,London,UK, 87654
```

My redshift table structure

```
ID CustomerName CustLocation Contact
```

if i load the csv it fails saying the extra columns found(because of 5 values in csv to 4 columns in table). How to make it treat LA,USA   or Street,London,UK as one entry

Quoting the values which contain commas doesnt work.

My source csv is in utf-8 encoding. and my lambda function is

COPY public.CustInfo FROM 's3://mybucket/salesfile.csv' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::99999999999:role/RedShiftRole' delimiter ',' ignoreheader 1 acceptinvchars

Comment: Your csv file is in invalid format. If commas are used as column separators, you have to use another character in the addresses. Alternatively, use quotes or another separator for the columns. Also note that you are not supposed to have spaces

Comment: why to not quote columns?

Comment: @DeepSpace we dont have liberty in choosing that, as the csv file is received over a mail and we have a lambda function to automate the reading and inserting the data

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes around your strings that will contain commas within them.

**Example:** (assuming the numbers are the `Contact` column's value)

```
ID, Name, Address, Contact
1, Kieron, "LA, USA", 67768800
2, Diana, "Baker Street,London,UK", 87654
```

Comment: have tried the same before, but the lambda function  still throws the error,
"errorMessage": "Load into table 'custinfo' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors'

the error in stl_load errors points to error type mismatch as char is being inserted into Contact column